# How do I extract dataframe from a string?

Tags: r

```
Table1 <- read.csv("table1.csv", header = T, sep = ",")
Table2 <- read.csv("table2.csv", header = T, sep = ",")
Table3 <- read.csv("table3.csv", header = T, sep = ",")
Table4 <- read.csv("table4.csv", header = T, sep = ",")
tables <- c("Table1", "Table2", "Table3", "Table4")
tables
[1] "Table1" "Table2" "Table3" "Table4"
tables[2]
[1] "Table2"
```

Above are my codes. I wish to extract the data in "tables". For example, when I select tables[2], I wish to see the data in table2.csv instead of just the word "Table2". How do I do this? Can anyone please help? Thanks!

Comment: Also, your line `tables <- c("Table1", "Table2", "Table3", "Table4")` stores strings and not the actual objects.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- I think what you need might be something like below

```
get(tables[2])
```

which fetches object `Table2` from your global environment

- If you save all objects in to a list named `tables`, i.e.,

```
tables <- list(Table1, Table2, Table3, Table4)
```

then you can call `tables[[2]]`

Answer (score 1):

Make a list of your tables if you really want:

```
tables <- list(Table1, Table2, Table3, Table4)
```

E.g.

```
tables[[1]]
```

What you've done is make a *vector* of *strings*, where your strings are "Table1", "Table2" etc. rather than storing the table objects.